# Word for a baby who was birthed by parents who were considerably older

Tags: single-word-requests

A singular term for a baby who was birthed by parents who were considerably older (like 45 to 70)?

Apparently I'm being pressed to give a "sample sentence" so here it is...

"My third son John is not as smart as my first one Paul...maybe it's because he was a [???] baby"

Comment: I doubt that such a word exists. My late father had an expression _autumn crocus_  for a child of elderly parents, but I've never heard anyone else use it.

Comment: Google actually autocompletes a question "What is a late in life baby" and one of the results mentions "late-life baby", although (if the context is clear) "late baby" might also do.

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be use"

Comment: @AndrewLeach - "Late baby" is apt to be interpreted as "deceased baby".

Comment: In some contexts ***oops baby*** can work.  But while the parents are typically older when an oops baby is conceived the emphasis is on “unplanned” rather than “older parents”.

Comment: A surprise, although not all surprises are late-life.

Comment: I have heard this expression: "He was an afterthought."

Comment: Along the lines of @HotLicks's *deceased baby*, a late baby could also be one carried beyond term, born after the due date.

Comment: Re @KateBunting's comment: Wikipedia indicates that "Colchicum autumnale, commonly known as **autumn crocus**, meadow saffron or naked ladies, is a toxic autumn-blooming flowering plant that resembles the true crocuses, but is a member of the plant family Colchicaceae, unlike the true crocuses which belong to the family Iridaceae. The name "naked ladies" comes from the fact that **the flowers emerge from the ground long before the leaves appear**." The bold text may shed light on her late father's use of the term, with the parents as the flowers and their offspring the leaves. Just a thought.

Comment: @RichardKayser Dad's explanation was simply that it was a child born in the autumn of its parents' lives.

Comment: @KateBunting I know. I'm sorry I didn't make it clearer that I understood that. Was running into space limitations and got lost in the editing. I just found it interesting that there was a plant called an autumn crocus and language that seemed vaguely relevant to the question posed. *Autumn crocus* is a most fitting and beautiful turn of phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Such a baby may be a *menopause baby* or a *change of life baby*. This expression technically refers to a baby born to a mother who is undergoing menopause, but may refer to a baby whose mother is of menopausal age. I am not aware of any term that refers to the father's age.

Comment: I guess the male situation isn't unusual enough to need a name (although there are claims of [health problems in children with older fathers](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/oct/22/the-perils-of-putting-off-fatherhood-why-it-poses-risks-to-childrens-physical-and-mental-health) reports just seem to refer to "older fathers" rather than a term for the children.)